# Grub-update repeats itself

Tags: dual-boot, apt, grub2

`grub-update` runs when I run `apt upgrade` or something like that with `apt`. That is understandable since it is probably the Linux kernel that is being updated. However, every time `grub-update` runs, irrespective of whether it is run exclusively or inclusively, it repeats 'finding' the same operating systems:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/images/grub/grub.png
Found background image: /usr/share/images/grub/grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Manjaro Linux (20.0) on /dev/sda10
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda11
Found Solus (4.1) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda8
Found Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (19.3) on /dev/sda9
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Manjaro Linux (20.0) on /dev/sda10
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda11
Found Solus (4.1) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda8
Found Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (19.3) on /dev/sda9
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Manjaro Linux (20.0) on /dev/sda10
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda11
Found Solus (4.1) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda8
Found Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (19.3) on /dev/sda9
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Manjaro Linux (20.0) on /dev/sda10
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda11
Found Solus (4.1) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda8


Found Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (19.3) on /dev/sda9
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Manjaro Linux (20.0) on /dev/sda10
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda11
Found Solus (4.1) on /dev/sda12
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda8
Found Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (19.3) on /dev/sda9
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

This time it stopped with 2 iterations or so. Usually, it goes on for a very long time. Is there a fix to this issue?

NB: That gap in between was because I pressed the `Enter` key there.

Comment: An easy workaround would be to remove multiple old kernels across multiple distros. This should speed up the process, but if you need a real fix, get the source code, and dig in.

Comment: @mikewhatever only the suggested kernels are present in the distros. Are they the issue over here?

Comment: I don't know what "suggested kernels" are, but if there is nothing to remove, perhaps there isn't an issue at all.